# PhoneGap 3.3 and Mobile Services HTML App on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, azure-mobile-services

I've installed the latest PhoneGap version (3.3), packaged my Mobile Services HTML application and hit the known authorization issue:

*Login is only supported from http:// and https:// URLs. Please host your page in a web server*

I've searched internet for this issue (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/a2386093-73cd-44fb-a418-4fa83a36c800/phonegap-apps-using-the-new-html-client-for-azure-mobile-services-is-not-working?forum=azuremobile) but the solution does not work for me. The project created by phonegap references `<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>` but even when i changed it to `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` it does not work.

Is there any solution for this issue?

My source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Report</title>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

myscript.js

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
            "https://myapp.azure-mobile.net/", "XXX");
        client.login("google").done(....
    },
};

$(document).ready(function documentReady() {
    app.initialize();
});
```

### Edit 21.12.

Apparently PhoneGap 3 does not report its version in `window.device.cordova` anymore where Mobile Services checks it. But even faking it did not help - after authorization on Google, it goes to empty page.

Comment: Getting this same error on an iOS project. Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Azure is still having problems with PhoneGap. Does the code work if you run it from a hosted location (Like jsfiddle)?

Comment: Did you try using the new Mobile Services PhoneGap quickstart? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-phonegap-get-started/. Also, do you have     <access origin="*" /> in your config.xml?

Comment: have you tried copying jquery and mobileservices js files to the local folder instead of referencing them to the web.

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248460/no-windows-azure-for-my-html5-game/23293220#23293220

Answer (score 0):

The version issue has been fixed recently with an update to the device core plugin.

device.cordova.version should correctly state what version you are running.

So if you intended to do a work around with it, you might be able to do it now.